# How do i split an array of elements based on inner value element?

Tags: php

As an input have an associate array like this:

```
$array[0]['id'] = 0;
$array[0]['name'] = 'first name';
$array[0]['phone'] = '+1 515 111 111';
$array[0]['for_id'] = 1;

$array[1]['id'] = 1;
$array[1]['name'] = 'first name1';
$array[1]['phone'] = '+1 515 222 222';
$array[1]['for_id'] = 1;

$array[2]['id'] = 0;
$array[2]['name'] = 'first name2';
$array[2]['phone'] = '+1 515 333 333';
$array[2]['for_id'] = 1;

$array[3]['id'] = 0;
$array[3]['name'] = 'first name3';
$array[3]['phone'] = '+1 515 444 444';
$array[3]['for_id'] = 2;

$array[4]['id'] = 0;
$array[4]['name'] = 'first name4';
$array[4]['phone'] = '+1 515 555 555';
$array[4]['for_id'] = 2;

$array[5]['id'] = 0;
$array[5]['name'] = 'first name5';
$array[5]['phone'] = '+1 515 666 666';
$array[5]['for_id'] = 2;
```

How do I split it in N separate arrays based on same value of `$array[]['for_id']`?

Like `$array1` will contain all elements from `$array` where `$array[]['for_id'] == 1;` and `$array2` with `$array[]['for_id'] == 2;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over the array and collect every item with the same for_id in a new array.

```
$t = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (!isset($t[$item['for_id']]) {
        $t[$item['for_id']] = array();
    }

    $t[$item['for_id']][] = $item;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

here is a similar way to Philipps' but doing exactly what you want, i.e. getting the name of the variable to match the for_id key value

```
$array[0]['id'] = 0;
$array[0]['name'] = 'first name';
$array[0]['phone'] = '+1 515 111 111';
$array[0]['for_id'] = 1;

$array[1]['id'] = 1;
$array[1]['name'] = 'first name1';
$array[1]['phone'] = '+1 515 222 222';
$array[1]['for_id'] = 1;

$array[2]['id'] = 0;
$array[2]['name'] = 'first name2';
$array[2]['phone'] = '+1 515 333 333';
$array[2]['for_id'] = 1;

$array[3]['id'] = 0;
$array[3]['name'] = 'first name3';
$array[3]['phone'] = '+1 515 444 444';
$array[3]['for_id'] = 2;

$array[4]['id'] = 0;
$array[4]['name'] = 'first name4';
$array[4]['phone'] = '+1 515 555 555';
$array[4]['for_id'] = 2;

$array[5]['id'] = 0;
$array[5]['name'] = 'first name5';
$array[5]['phone'] = '+1 515 666 666';
$array[5]['for_id'] = 2;



foreach($array as $arr){
    $int = $arr['for_id'];
    $arrName  = 'array' . $int;

    if(!isset($$arrName ))
    {
        $$arrName =array();
    }
    array_push($$arrName, $arr);

}

echo 'First array ' . json_encode($array1);
echo 'Second array ' . json_encode($array2);
```

Comment: What I have added as an answer just shows how to get $array1 and $array2 out of the dataset/($array) as asked by starnzd. The result is a uncontrolled and unstructured number of arrays after the foreach loop is run and it all depends on the real value of $array. You can run foreach($array1 as $arr)... after if this is what you are asking. I have echoed using json_encode as it gives you a JSON representation of the result easier to read than a var_dump result